# Are there other known tensor-like constructions for $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

To construct the tensor product of two modules $M,N$, you start with the free group on $M\times N$ and take the quotient of $F(M\times N)$ by the subgroup generated by the elements of the form :

$$
(m_1 + m_2, n) - (m_1, n) + (m_2, n) = 0
\dots 
$$
(there are two other forms), which essentially says that those expressions in the tensor group are equal to $0$.

What other constructions are there that are similar to this?  That are algebraic like the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested only in $R$-modules? For example, there is tensor product for right and left semigroup actions.

Comment: Sure show me that one if ya want